# Alter the output of a time format if one or more dates are zero

Tags: php

in my php script i can output how long someone has been following a channel on twitch.tv.

the code part doing this is here:

```
  $followdate = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime($result["created_at"])));
  $heute = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s'));
  $differenz = $followdate->diff($heute);

  echo $differenz->format('%y Jahre, %m Monate, %d Tage');
```

i.e for one user i get the output "0 Jahre, 2 Monate, 12 Tage" but since the "Jahre (Years)" are 0 is there a way to say that it shouldnt output this one so it only say "2 Monate, 12 Tage"?

Comment: Check if years equal zero?

Comment: could you provide a example? im not that familiar with  php and know if-else statements only from java. i tried one of those already some days ago but it failed horribly heh

Comment: If is not rocket science http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could do something like this:

```
$followdate = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s',strtotime($result["created_at"])));
$heute = new DateTime(date('d-m-Y h:i:s'));
$diff = $followdate->diff($heute);

if($diff->y > 0) {
    $f = '%y Jahre, %m Monate, %d Tage';
} elseif($diff->m > 0) {
    $f = '%m Monate, %d Tage';
} else {
    $f = '%d Tage';
}


echo $diff->format($f);
```

Comment: Oh, thats quite simple. i thought that i have to make couple if/else things for either if year AND months are <=0 but i think i can go for that way :D